# capistrano insisting on password

Tags: capistrano

First, my teammate is successfully deploying on almost exactly the same setup and using the exact same config as me re deploy. Therefore, cannot be a deploy configuration issue, there is nothing local or unique to any of our machines.

Second, I can successfully login via my machine using ssh user@server.com without password prompt.

However, I have tried everything to stop capistrano asking this question:

--recursive; fi"
    servers: ["myserver.com"]
Password:
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back

I have tried every single password I have, and not entering a password. I don't even know what this password is for. Is it SSH? Because I don't even have a password protected key file.

I'm totally lost and I've literally been debugging this for 5 hours now without a single change in status. I'd really appreciate some help on how I can find out what the problem is.

Note, cap deploy simply works for my teammate using same config, same server. Everything, except different key file (note mine works and tested via ssh command).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you *have* to specify user@server.com to SSH to your server successfully (i.e., do you have a different username on your remote server from your local machine)?

You might just need to tell Capistrano what username it should be using to connect with by adding it to your deploy.rb:

```or-tag-here
set :user, "your-username"
```

You could also change the default username SSH will pick for that server by using `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host your.server.name
User your-username
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I resolved the issue now (thankfully). Turns out although I was using root to deploy, capistrano was using a default user to connect via ssh to the server - yet using root to connect to git.